# laravel graphql playground Client authentication failed", for login access

Tags: graphql

I am working on a project where i'm facing problem while configuring graphql. When i'm trying to login it shows error on client authentication. Here's the code i have now:

```js
mutation{
login(data:{
  username:"avc@gmail.com",
  password:"123456789",
}){
  access_token
}
}
```

error is:

```js
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "message": "Client authentication failed",
      "extensions": {
        "guards": [],
        "category": "authentication"
      },
      "locations": [
        {
          "line": 2,
          "column": 3
        }
      ],
      "path": [
        "login"
      ],
```

Comment: This is way to broad. What have you tried to debug your problem? What makes you think that is is solely related to GraphQL and not on your personal implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

this problem Solution command is 
**php artisan passport:client --password password**

That means you have create client password